# Mongo Uneven Shard Distribution

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Initially our server started with 4 shards. After running the site for several years we decided to add 4 more shards to help alleviate the load on the existing servers, now the problem is that the shard distribution has been very uneven and the new servers have not been helping with the load due to this. The following is an example of the shard distribution from one of our bigger collections

```
Shard shard0000 contains 15.56% data, 15.56% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0001 contains 15.12% data, 15.12% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0002 contains 16.73% data, 16.73% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0003 contains 15.62% data, 15.62% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0004 contains 9.31% data, 9.31% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0005 contains 9.35% data, 9.35% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0006 contains 9.12% data, 9.12% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
Shard shard0007 contains 9.16% data, 9.16% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 143B
```

The balancer has been running during off peak hours, but it doesn't seem to be fixing the uneven distribution.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: Added the `sh.status()` for the collection

```
    shard key: { "hash" : 1 }
    chunks:
        shard0004   21
        shard0007   20
        shard0006   20
        shard0005   21
        shard0002   24
        shard0003   24
        shard0001   24
        shard0000   25
    { "hash" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "hash" : "0096c316a754c8f628793402d6a217fa" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(28, 0) 
    { "hash" : "0096c316a754c8f628793402d6a217fa" } -->> { "hash" : "01767732a77657e2e67e3b1d1afa6216" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(65, 0) 
    { "hash" : "01767732a77657e2e67e3b1d1afa6216" } -->> { "hash" : "0256566c72f3d75dff16b5740bf60df3" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(66, 0) 
    { "hash" : "0256566c72f3d75dff16b5740bf60df3" } -->> { "hash" : "0323ebd846f1897351bf904092492253" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(68, 0) 
    { "hash" : "0323ebd846f1897351bf904092492253" } -->> { "hash" : "03f0faf2bc0b91570816c1811b1bf89e" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(69, 0) 
    { "hash" : "03f0faf2bc0b91570816c1811b1bf89e" } -->> { "hash" : "04acc3c7bbfb66570601e88a498598ae" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(73, 0) 
    { "hash" : "04acc3c7bbfb66570601e88a498598ae" } -->> { "hash" : "056891c4103e62d7f6d90afc6bc0113c" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(74, 0) 
    { "hash" : "056891c4103e62d7f6d90afc6bc0113c" } -->> { "hash" : "06250a5a7c6d0985c1b0d975d005b216" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(75, 0) 
    { "hash" : "06250a5a7c6d0985c1b0d975d005b216" } -->> { "hash" : "06e17baaaf9c74bb4a94e80b8c5be56b" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(76, 0) 
    { "hash" : "06e17baaaf9c74bb4a94e80b8c5be56b" } -->> { "hash" : "079c56d507673f2a7a0f11aad27da3c7" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(79, 0) 
    { "hash" : "079c56d507673f2a7a0f11aad27da3c7" } -->> { "hash" : "08585cf98b8f1d5027ead5622d770e32" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(80, 0) 
    { "hash" : "08585cf98b8f1d5027ead5622d770e32" } -->> { "hash" : "091404f3a9faf42c75c1fe7ccd87c1ba" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(84, 0) 
    { "hash" : "091404f3a9faf42c75c1fe7ccd87c1ba" } -->> { "hash" : "09cfc86384d3b0ff5c4ed3ee8ecfda3d" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(86, 0) 
    { "hash" : "09cfc86384d3b0ff5c4ed3ee8ecfda3d" } -->> { "hash" : "0b0719d7022b9d6d831c4253dd9861ed" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(87, 0) 
    { "hash" : "0b0719d7022b9d6d831c4253dd9861ed" } -->> { "hash" : "0f601a06372d8874b4ff4dc58b9ac0e6" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(87, 1) 
    { "hash" : "0f601a06372d8874b4ff4dc58b9ac0e6" } -->> { "hash" : "10c7fb288ab4657d63c40df3cee5eec5" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(60, 16) 
    { "hash" : "10c7fb288ab4657d63c40df3cee5eec5" } -->> { "hash" : "121a5790eea9e48113dbf13bc920381c" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(71, 4) 
    { "hash" : "121a5790eea9e48113dbf13bc920381c" } -->> { "hash" : "1346f4d9e28529070ddd5d7ce630b824" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(86, 16) 
    { "hash" : "1346f4d9e28529070ddd5d7ce630b824" } -->> { "hash" : "1692c5e0adbae6847c1595976cf308e8" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(86, 17) 
    { "hash" : "1692c5e0adbae6847c1595976cf308e8" } -->> { "hash" : "1817e8910d67a14a1ccb0ce68074f283" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(24, 0) 
    { "hash" : "1817e8910d67a14a1ccb0ce68074f283" } -->> { "hash" : "199d8813d2533204d363c0eb05508d5a" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(25, 0) 
    { "hash" : "199d8813d2533204d363c0eb05508d5a" } -->> { "hash" : "1b23becfb6b654b7a830311a709c1eb8" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(26, 0) 
    { "hash" : "1b23becfb6b654b7a830311a709c1eb8" } -->> { "hash" : "1caa0fe0fc3a76ce12de781137cbb2e0" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(27, 0) 
    { "hash" : "1caa0fe0fc3a76ce12de781137cbb2e0" } -->> { "hash" : "1e83e11811d7dd326f15f1ff16fb8d7f" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(43, 0) 
    { "hash" : "1e83e11811d7dd326f15f1ff16fb8d7f" } -->> { "hash" : "204473f57239f124b5e2fa6a0ce5b3de" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(45, 0) 
    { "hash" : "204473f57239f124b5e2fa6a0ce5b3de" } -->> { "hash" : "2122bff14ade54acabf809fcdd9fb3fb" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(59, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2122bff14ade54acabf809fcdd9fb3fb" } -->> { "hash" : "2201978401c65849099954200f0d98c6" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(61, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2201978401c65849099954200f0d98c6" } -->> { "hash" : "2365f97f0af5b10ef082ac2fa94213c7" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(62, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2365f97f0af5b10ef082ac2fa94213c7" } -->> { "hash" : "2423ecbcb32549275ea1bbead7f1a6d2" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(63, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2423ecbcb32549275ea1bbead7f1a6d2" } -->> { "hash" : "24e204818b0e5dfa8c62c1840b7b36c9" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(64, 0) 
    { "hash" : "24e204818b0e5dfa8c62c1840b7b36c9" } -->> { "hash" : "26a8fcef33cdb12ca0f9c8e964884e25" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(12, 0) 
    { "hash" : "26a8fcef33cdb12ca0f9c8e964884e25" } -->> { "hash" : "286fdb86a0ad33fce45d48ba8aeaed76" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(13, 0) 
    { "hash" : "286fdb86a0ad33fce45d48ba8aeaed76" } -->> { "hash" : "2a36d5c6818e42393dff73fd9d36825e" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(14, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2a36d5c6818e42393dff73fd9d36825e" } -->> { "hash" : "2bfd3f123776c882402fb366caae69ef" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(15, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2bfd3f123776c882402fb366caae69ef" } -->> { "hash" : "2dc863db22aa527a1ab5c38fb4c5b79f" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(16, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2dc863db22aa527a1ab5c38fb4c5b79f" } -->> { "hash" : "2f952392172750d70ad3b33e52409dd7" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(17, 0) 
    { "hash" : "2f952392172750d70ad3b33e52409dd7" } -->> { "hash" : "316103318efd305dba54b3de6aeaa4e8" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(18, 0) 
    { "hash" : "316103318efd305dba54b3de6aeaa4e8" } -->> { "hash" : "332f1bacc24a66fd63d9a709a473d883" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(19, 0) 
    { "hash" : "332f1bacc24a66fd63d9a709a473d883" } -->> { "hash" : "3494d9e02071844bcc3d452f9279589f" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(29, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3494d9e02071844bcc3d452f9279589f" } -->> { "hash" : "35fb652c9a3222f995fe94f43cc771e0" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(30, 0) 
    { "hash" : "35fb652c9a3222f995fe94f43cc771e0" } -->> { "hash" : "3762fd13a6ce6ad6660b760762db63de" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(31, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3762fd13a6ce6ad6660b760762db63de" } -->> { "hash" : "38ca4719fbd5c7043d406a0c3212f50d" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(32, 0) 
    { "hash" : "38ca4719fbd5c7043d406a0c3212f50d" } -->> { "hash" : "39ba62b8fc12ec9a82e814ae22abc639" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(57, 0) 
    { "hash" : "39ba62b8fc12ec9a82e814ae22abc639" } -->> { "hash" : "3aab998023c585aee431faf50ccad1be" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(58, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3aab998023c585aee431faf50ccad1be" } -->> { "hash" : "3c3b142b4600a277253d62a9e59495fb" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(60, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3c3b142b4600a277253d62a9e59495fb" } -->> { "hash" : "3d91ce54fad93712c7cac10143618671" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(67, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3d91ce54fad93712c7cac10143618671" } -->> { "hash" : "3e9e53ff48d9a9da3c783937f52ac178" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(70, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3e9e53ff48d9a9da3c783937f52ac178" } -->> { "hash" : "3fab92c377ea67884e77eec02751b822" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(71, 0) 
    { "hash" : "3fab92c377ea67884e77eec02751b822" } -->> { "hash" : "406b30881e6627f7cd5b4473e7b295b5" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(72, 0) 
    { "hash" : "406b30881e6627f7cd5b4473e7b295b5" } -->> { "hash" : "412bbe8c021e45cd03389921abef23d8" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(77, 0) 
    { "hash" : "412bbe8c021e45cd03389921abef23d8" } -->> { "hash" : "41d96299f6865b2dc1791a5e8d3870fa" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(82, 0) 
    { "hash" : "41d96299f6865b2dc1791a5e8d3870fa" } -->> { "hash" : "4287d3ac80457ced47c2204a61c89c4e" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(83, 0) 
    { "hash" : "4287d3ac80457ced47c2204a61c89c4e" } -->> { "hash" : "43c9eac00f88103926311705c65a592f" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(85, 0) 
    { "hash" : "43c9eac00f88103926311705c65a592f" } -->> { "hash" : "448cc55c43dcc80a5b3ee365408294de" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(90, 0) 
    { "hash" : "448cc55c43dcc80a5b3ee365408294de" } -->> { "hash" : "454fd98710d7f6b8a6ca42c116a720be" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(91, 0) 
    { "hash" : "454fd98710d7f6b8a6ca42c116a720be" } -->> { "hash" : "4613a1f5e7623aa2b8ce5220ef207428" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(92, 0) 
    { "hash" : "4613a1f5e7623aa2b8ce5220ef207428" } -->> { "hash" : "46d6b1749a62824ec317fda78d436ec4" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(93, 0) 
    { "hash" : "46d6b1749a62824ec317fda78d436ec4" } -->> { "hash" : "479ad065a429d297cae7234419eb1d9d" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(94, 0) 
    { "hash" : "479ad065a429d297cae7234419eb1d9d" } -->> { "hash" : "485e5b8cf9f8f5a8245f7b893ac60240" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(95, 0) 
    { "hash" : "485e5b8cf9f8f5a8245f7b893ac60240" } -->> { "hash" : "49b2ee2792b86873e7891f43453478b6" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(95, 1) 
    { "hash" : "49b2ee2792b86873e7891f43453478b6" } -->> { "hash" : "4aee88c9976990eb2f2e52a6ea6b4d0b" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(81, 14) 
    { "hash" : "4aee88c9976990eb2f2e52a6ea6b4d0b" } -->> { "hash" : "4c042e5b974325dd87e8c2093cb7809f" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(91, 4) 
    { "hash" : "4c042e5b974325dd87e8c2093cb7809f" } -->> { "hash" : "4f01c23152e8c23eb685f0f1ccd3574a" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(91, 5) 
    { "hash" : "4f01c23152e8c23eb685f0f1ccd3574a" } -->> { "hash" : "507cddde3ffb51492a3a32457b3c8680" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(60, 4) 
    { "hash" : "507cddde3ffb51492a3a32457b3c8680" } -->> { "hash" : "51d74c15a9832c5ab881354835e7c3f0" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(66, 10) 
    { "hash" : "51d74c15a9832c5ab881354835e7c3f0" } -->> { "hash" : "5327cd130720e69b56164d5bc7cf47e2" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(76, 4) 
    { "hash" : "5327cd130720e69b56164d5bc7cf47e2" } -->> { "hash" : "54426cbf461bb1a3a43f44012f8afaf8" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(89, 4) 
    { "hash" : "54426cbf461bb1a3a43f44012f8afaf8" } -->> { "hash" : "558078d76f9ba43477bacbed2640414b" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(89, 5) 
    { "hash" : "558078d76f9ba43477bacbed2640414b" } -->> { "hash" : "56fac1c343349227bc39c5f72be82dd4" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(56, 14) 
    { "hash" : "56fac1c343349227bc39c5f72be82dd4" } -->> { "hash" : "5854da68fae12e4afdb32ec5172698cc" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(66, 12) 
    { "hash" : "5854da68fae12e4afdb32ec5172698cc" } -->> { "hash" : "59a4d26a918d536e8da3eb3c48b8b66e" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(71, 8) 
    { "hash" : "59a4d26a918d536e8da3eb3c48b8b66e" } -->> { "hash" : "5c134f1e081b25e0be638c97ac45f9fe" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(71, 9) 
    { "hash" : "5c134f1e081b25e0be638c97ac45f9fe" } -->> { "hash" : "5dd232bd88633d2a6d8b81a26d6a4bf6" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(39, 18) 
    { "hash" : "5dd232bd88633d2a6d8b81a26d6a4bf6" } -->> { "hash" : "5f69838082adb58883e5e4b6ac36ebe7" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(49, 16) 
    { "hash" : "5f69838082adb58883e5e4b6ac36ebe7" } -->> { "hash" : "60b31719bcb9d2e9da906c8ef24d6b58" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(81, 4) 
    { "hash" : "60b31719bcb9d2e9da906c8ef24d6b58" } -->> { "hash" : "61d843a4a9fb8c3ded6806732d8d7c32" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(87, 6) 
    { "hash" : "61d843a4a9fb8c3ded6806732d8d7c32" } -->> { "hash" : "6480d1d4442a1d46d750f68744c53d94" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(87, 7) 
    { "hash" : "6480d1d4442a1d46d750f68744c53d94" } -->> { "hash" : "663e424de9bd7f712ea89caf50d73cf5" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(39, 16) 
    { "hash" : "663e424de9bd7f712ea89caf50d73cf5" } -->> { "hash" : "67edb97c800788a891fb500deb400256" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(49, 6) 
    { "hash" : "67edb97c800788a891fb500deb400256" } -->> { "hash" : "697083691bee96e22eb50bdbefb8917b" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(56, 6) 
    { "hash" : "697083691bee96e22eb50bdbefb8917b" } -->> { "hash" : "6ae3c71cdff25b79d4102c2863d422fb" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(60, 12) 
    { "hash" : "6ae3c71cdff25b79d4102c2863d422fb" } -->> { "hash" : "6c33fe587906a9f7bf6bcab78c6c1608" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(76, 14) 
    { "hash" : "6c33fe587906a9f7bf6bcab78c6c1608" } -->> { "hash" : "6ed3040f678900d16c948ba19fe786bc" } on : shard0003 Timestamp(76, 15) 
    { "hash" : "6ed3040f678900d16c948ba19fe786bc" } -->> { "hash" : "702c035c360f5278d683f77606c69ebb" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(66, 8) 
    { "hash" : "702c035c360f5278d683f77606c69ebb" } -->> { "hash" : "71760e9813a6229d9116801328db471d" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(78, 6) 
    { "hash" : "71760e9813a6229d9116801328db471d" } -->> { "hash" : "74973d49c7393320989bd87d212e74e0" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(78, 7) 
    { "hash" : "74973d49c7393320989bd87d212e74e0" } -->> { "hash" : "761336135e0d2046bb5924e32c989d0f" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(56, 12) 
    { "hash" : "761336135e0d2046bb5924e32c989d0f" } -->> { "hash" : "7789da25534f6a446163857b6ca80585" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(60, 6) 
    { "hash" : "7789da25534f6a446163857b6ca80585" } -->> { "hash" : "78dba031c7d4f5130a7138a990d03777" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(71, 6) 
    { "hash" : "78dba031c7d4f5130a7138a990d03777" } -->> { "hash" : "7b9d5cd8befd19bb11b26a2063e99a79" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(71, 7) 
    { "hash" : "7b9d5cd8befd19bb11b26a2063e99a79" } -->> { "hash" : "7d22b7f188a06e82a2d539257e134141" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(56, 4) 
    { "hash" : "7d22b7f188a06e82a2d539257e134141" } -->> { "hash" : "7e8afb407f89298187a18109d0c0f9e6" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(60, 18) 
    { "hash" : "7e8afb407f89298187a18109d0c0f9e6" } -->> { "hash" : "7fef03cc84df8c33ec72904140b9a5fe" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(60, 24) 
    { "hash" : "7fef03cc84df8c33ec72904140b9a5fe" } -->> { "hash" : "81380bbdd0d4d07c5dd600250f0444af" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(81, 8) 
    { "hash" : "81380bbdd0d4d07c5dd600250f0444af" } -->> { "hash" : "82e680a43d730066c6d6d00f1be4e32a" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(81, 9) 
    { "hash" : "82e680a43d730066c6d6d00f1be4e32a" } -->> { "hash" : "846f27eef8b26bc874a030920d6f2dc8" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(53, 8) 
    { "hash" : "846f27eef8b26bc874a030920d6f2dc8" } -->> { "hash" : "85e2740d4d83be8292c24412db7a00a1" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(60, 10) 
    { "hash" : "85e2740d4d83be8292c24412db7a00a1" } -->> { "hash" : "873ed6e94dbe4d4b798cf819a7be9f87" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(66, 6) 
    { "hash" : "873ed6e94dbe4d4b798cf819a7be9f87" } -->> { "hash" : "886dab713c8c5fe42494dc487232b405" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(86, 14) 
    { "hash" : "886dab713c8c5fe42494dc487232b405" } -->> { "hash" : "8b453172ecbdb48e5877e6cfc7b79ee3" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(86, 15) 
    { "hash" : "8b453172ecbdb48e5877e6cfc7b79ee3" } -->> { "hash" : "8c148b1f1f6976ac486993ef2701e934" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(78, 0) 
    { "hash" : "8c148b1f1f6976ac486993ef2701e934" } -->> { "hash" : "8ce30d15961ce62b15e60eaf814ce45e" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(81, 0) 
    { "hash" : "8ce30d15961ce62b15e60eaf814ce45e" } -->> { "hash" : "8d9918897a24d6a64456b784f490b048" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(88, 0) 
    { "hash" : "8d9918897a24d6a64456b784f490b048" } -->> { "hash" : "8e4fabc8ca097b36debc0896b8b9a974" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(89, 0) 
    { "hash" : "8e4fabc8ca097b36debc0896b8b9a974" } -->> { "hash" : "8fb407f11e1212c4240ec06a979615b0" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(89, 1) 
    { "hash" : "8fb407f11e1212c4240ec06a979615b0" } -->> { "hash" : "90fdd7ab184255c02b99edda101796ae" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(78, 8) 
    { "hash" : "90fdd7ab184255c02b99edda101796ae" } -->> { "hash" : "94337e2ed8741d02028c33f5a238f2cd" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(78, 9) 
    { "hash" : "94337e2ed8741d02028c33f5a238f2cd" } -->> { "hash" : "95f40c00417a5a8ee692d459570a8551" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(39, 8) 
    { "hash" : "95f40c00417a5a8ee692d459570a8551" } -->> { "hash" : "97a4a2771fbf4e2633dae4d3009cb8b1" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(49, 4) 
    { "hash" : "97a4a2771fbf4e2633dae4d3009cb8b1" } -->> { "hash" : "99407767d9a265c1b19e506500b44aa5" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(49, 10) 
    { "hash" : "99407767d9a265c1b19e506500b44aa5" } -->> { "hash" : "9acc0d7e5308c0cb60d959db94d33318" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(53, 4) 
    { "hash" : "9acc0d7e5308c0cb60d959db94d33318" } -->> { "hash" : "9c419a178e32a05c2650cd31efcc858d" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(60, 8) 
    { "hash" : "9c419a178e32a05c2650cd31efcc858d" } -->> { "hash" : "9d8f77175b877cfc8febdf733e0a3f7a" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(76, 16) 
    { "hash" : "9d8f77175b877cfc8febdf733e0a3f7a" } -->> { "hash" : "9fbacbf5c378be80449aefcc198bfc68" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(76, 17) 
    { "hash" : "9fbacbf5c378be80449aefcc198bfc68" } -->> { "hash" : "a173b41b16b63a0102175a9e86052afd" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(45, 10) 
    { "hash" : "a173b41b16b63a0102175a9e86052afd" } -->> { "hash" : "a30085714610e8796ba21edc42665bf1" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(49, 24) 
    { "hash" : "a30085714610e8796ba21edc42665bf1" } -->> { "hash" : "a431f8333c13d93aadc195bb5b77ba7d" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(86, 12) 
    { "hash" : "a431f8333c13d93aadc195bb5b77ba7d" } -->> { "hash" : "a54f025a25dfd94a9d2b645c1d4f105a" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(87, 8) 
    { "hash" : "a54f025a25dfd94a9d2b645c1d4f105a" } -->> { "hash" : "a8c25e1ed3f156f7bf1b6ac03157b7c2" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(87, 9) 
    { "hash" : "a8c25e1ed3f156f7bf1b6ac03157b7c2" } -->> { "hash" : "aa28021b4afb48bd9624017ac9daf801" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(60, 22) 
    { "hash" : "aa28021b4afb48bd9624017ac9daf801" } -->> { "hash" : "ab7803bd7d42268f4595e461213b6359" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(76, 10) 
    { "hash" : "ab7803bd7d42268f4595e461213b6359" } -->> { "hash" : "acab1ba0757f0fa9a92c37eddd4db966" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(86, 10) 
    { "hash" : "acab1ba0757f0fa9a92c37eddd4db966" } -->> { "hash" : "aec8dd8cef8c5228c096615a471843a2" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(86, 11) 
    { "hash" : "aec8dd8cef8c5228c096615a471843a2" } -->> { "hash" : "b02fd4a1e43f5f991386583e5b448917" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(60, 20) 
    { "hash" : "b02fd4a1e43f5f991386583e5b448917" } -->> { "hash" : "b17f660d7f3a5f814e74054b3d79786c" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(76, 12) 
    { "hash" : "b17f660d7f3a5f814e74054b3d79786c" } -->> { "hash" : "b2c9640546e152d22e73ffa8522a751d" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(81, 6) 
    { "hash" : "b2c9640546e152d22e73ffa8522a751d" } -->> { "hash" : "b509b2eee0d8dec3798aa861ddbc624e" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(81, 7) 
    { "hash" : "b509b2eee0d8dec3798aa861ddbc624e" } -->> { "hash" : "b6ab24b872b93da5c1ddf2ec81b7aad4" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(20, 0) 
    { "hash" : "b6ab24b872b93da5c1ddf2ec81b7aad4" } -->> { "hash" : "b84c2a20458a7e4d23f63cacc43059db" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(21, 0) 
    { "hash" : "b84c2a20458a7e4d23f63cacc43059db" } -->> { "hash" : "b9ed7189c285195f4b2d97ebf85544a8" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(22, 0) 
    { "hash" : "b9ed7189c285195f4b2d97ebf85544a8" } -->> { "hash" : "bb8eea70aa9f24ca27c2c750d3cfecba" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(23, 0) 
    { "hash" : "bb8eea70aa9f24ca27c2c750d3cfecba" } -->> { "hash" : "bd37277ad4c7195a731e87d5156d399f" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(33, 0) 
    { "hash" : "bd37277ad4c7195a731e87d5156d399f" } -->> { "hash" : "bedfe4b2b12104ea2763b024e5ea0f91" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(34, 0) 
    { "hash" : "bedfe4b2b12104ea2763b024e5ea0f91" } -->> { "hash" : "c087e0f9bfb67d10108f2c71c294a910" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(35, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c087e0f9bfb67d10108f2c71c294a910" } -->> { "hash" : "c22f1c97f1664e067139fc2102cdb073" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(36, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c22f1c97f1664e067139fc2102cdb073" } -->> { "hash" : "c406a5973c2cac6b8cad5ad8698ac5cd" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(37, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c406a5973c2cac6b8cad5ad8698ac5cd" } -->> { "hash" : "c53057a7469ddb3f51a062db61c32eef" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(38, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c53057a7469ddb3f51a062db61c32eef" } -->> { "hash" : "c65a275c435186bdc0054a6439b2f7f3" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(39, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c65a275c435186bdc0054a6439b2f7f3" } -->> { "hash" : "c828020eee54d15dc00dba8b1561a582" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(40, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c828020eee54d15dc00dba8b1561a582" } -->> { "hash" : "c95491422e66ffc61951e7ef57d29a13" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(41, 0) 
    { "hash" : "c95491422e66ffc61951e7ef57d29a13" } -->> { "hash" : "ca81b2a02dc7c0d4f721179e2f48a757" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(42, 0) 
    { "hash" : "ca81b2a02dc7c0d4f721179e2f48a757" } -->> { "hash" : "cc41dc3b261b657f143cdf77153efcab" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(44, 0) 
    { "hash" : "cc41dc3b261b657f143cdf77153efcab" } -->> { "hash" : "cd5615582591ffd36f27ccc450c524ac" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(46, 0) 
    { "hash" : "cd5615582591ffd36f27ccc450c524ac" } -->> { "hash" : "ce69b42112fe21dcec992b0d13b50290" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(47, 0) 
    { "hash" : "ce69b42112fe21dcec992b0d13b50290" } -->> { "hash" : "cf7da3b87db92247aac8088d2a9dac13" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(48, 0) 
    { "hash" : "cf7da3b87db92247aac8088d2a9dac13" } -->> { "hash" : "d0925310a75c383588e09930430babb8" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(49, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d0925310a75c383588e09930430babb8" } -->> { "hash" : "d1a5fb98c9dca1ad1001890eb4b6cd10" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(50, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d1a5fb98c9dca1ad1001890eb4b6cd10" } -->> { "hash" : "d2ba22c4727afcc1536a2771375b8b9b" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(51, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d2ba22c4727afcc1536a2771375b8b9b" } -->> { "hash" : "d3cdb27b6bedf7d0fef98f20f8722c90" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(52, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d3cdb27b6bedf7d0fef98f20f8722c90" } -->> { "hash" : "d4e0eae78a93c8f8b5c8715b05e0906e" } on : shard0007 Timestamp(53, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d4e0eae78a93c8f8b5c8715b05e0906e" } -->> { "hash" : "d5bda846189ab8dbb2dfa167183d70e8" } on : shard0004 Timestamp(54, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d5bda846189ab8dbb2dfa167183d70e8" } -->> { "hash" : "d69ab5e2e3b44cdf045e2141dca9dc61" } on : shard0005 Timestamp(55, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d69ab5e2e3b44cdf045e2141dca9dc61" } -->> { "hash" : "d827e9558705964d23015e825a07118b" } on : shard0006 Timestamp(56, 0) 
    { "hash" : "d827e9558705964d23015e825a07118b" } -->> { "hash" : "d8cf0635028edb5243ddb7f0a076cfa8" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(95, 2) 
    { "hash" : "d8cf0635028edb5243ddb7f0a076cfa8" } -->> { "hash" : "d975fe6138a5106b43b1ed710279e7f1" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(95, 3) 
    { "hash" : "d975fe6138a5106b43b1ed710279e7f1" } -->> { "hash" : "db0f11ef744dd20e6e46ade8f96ff552" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(76, 9) 
    { "hash" : "db0f11ef744dd20e6e46ade8f96ff552" } -->> { "hash" : "dc5ec4b91fb2f881f8c335c2323dd6e3" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(76, 6) 
    { "hash" : "dc5ec4b91fb2f881f8c335c2323dd6e3" } -->> { "hash" : "ddf94593fb52923b45fceb9b52da7950" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(76, 7) 
    { "hash" : "ddf94593fb52923b45fceb9b52da7950" } -->> { "hash" : "dfb94d7e507c1a138bb8096271137dc1" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(39, 10) 
    { "hash" : "dfb94d7e507c1a138bb8096271137dc1" } -->> { "hash" : "e17539f28ffc06acbf4292f94a410e0b" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(45, 4) 
    { "hash" : "e17539f28ffc06acbf4292f94a410e0b" } -->> { "hash" : "e30d8cf587d9323c664620a951b5d918" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(49, 12) 
    { "hash" : "e30d8cf587d9323c664620a951b5d918" } -->> { "hash" : "e463550ca8f2d6d490930ac207561373" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(69, 4) 
    { "hash" : "e463550ca8f2d6d490930ac207561373" } -->> { "hash" : "e59d3288d6dc5c1fc4a6d138ba821429" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(86, 4) 
    { "hash" : "e59d3288d6dc5c1fc4a6d138ba821429" } -->> { "hash" : "e6c45710d115db22b183bd6498165206" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(87, 4) 
    { "hash" : "e6c45710d115db22b183bd6498165206" } -->> { "hash" : "e963f2db893ecac1092f180831333d55" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(87, 5) 
    { "hash" : "e963f2db893ecac1092f180831333d55" } -->> { "hash" : "eb43b54221873ba4ff6fab011618f39e" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(32, 8) 
    { "hash" : "eb43b54221873ba4ff6fab011618f39e" } -->> { "hash" : "ed0c264fe9019965ecd7ff5b41c9d23b" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(39, 4) 
    { "hash" : "ed0c264fe9019965ecd7ff5b41c9d23b" } -->> { "hash" : "eec5cc8e19a75d4af5ede17a44edb173" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(45, 12) 
    { "hash" : "eec5cc8e19a75d4af5ede17a44edb173" } -->> { "hash" : "f0503b2876715bdadddb9ff1da3c85d5" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(53, 6) 
    { "hash" : "f0503b2876715bdadddb9ff1da3c85d5" } -->> { "hash" : "f1d2ee4b2fd272eced421f3add4714f5" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(56, 8) 
    { "hash" : "f1d2ee4b2fd272eced421f3add4714f5" } -->> { "hash" : "f319f2a83d66adc96f550de8f5198968" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(81, 10) 
    { "hash" : "f319f2a83d66adc96f550de8f5198968" } -->> { "hash" : "f4837ce70d316e8927183e59462a8009" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(81, 11) 
    { "hash" : "f4837ce70d316e8927183e59462a8009" } -->> { "hash" : "f662ad89d4166692388f34eb64e8f98b" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(32, 6) 
    { "hash" : "f662ad89d4166692388f34eb64e8f98b" } -->> { "hash" : "f81d4be726d786777e9033292bc54cf9" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(45, 6) 
    { "hash" : "f81d4be726d786777e9033292bc54cf9" } -->> { "hash" : "f9ab2ccbd3796823054a9ac6315b9ef9" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(49, 20) 
    { "hash" : "f9ab2ccbd3796823054a9ac6315b9ef9" } -->> { "hash" : "faf631b3f9f5bbf5ed004761784aab59" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(78, 4) 
    { "hash" : "faf631b3f9f5bbf5ed004761784aab59" } -->> { "hash" : "fc2cd371bf17ba7bebf7f50cdcf8410f" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(86, 8) 
    { "hash" : "fc2cd371bf17ba7bebf7f50cdcf8410f" } -->> { "hash" : "fffd8df39bff09604b965fd80fcfcbd1" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(86, 9) 
    { "hash" : "fffd8df39bff09604b965fd80fcfcbd1" } -->> { "hash" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0001 Timestamp(4, 1)
```

**Update**: Added results for lastMigration

```
{
        "clientAddr" : ":27017",
        "time" : ISODate("2014-07-28T17:09:37.603Z"),
        "what" : "moveChunk.to",
        "details" : {
                "min" : {
                        "hash" : "479ad065a429d297cae7234419eb1d9d"
                },
                "max" : {
                        "hash" : "485e5b8cf9f8f5a8245f7b893ac60240"
                },
                "step1 of 5" : 3,
                "step2 of 5" : 0,
                "step3 of 5" : 197310,
                "step4 of 5" : 2,
                "step5 of 5" : 591
        }
}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: what's your shard key?

Comment: can you give us a sh.status as well? Though this is really a dba question

Comment: @JohnPetrone the collection contains a "hash" that's generated in the client side as sort of an ID. That's what we use as the shard key.

Comment: @Sammaye updated the question with the sh.status() for the collection

Comment: I'd like you to run sh._lastMigration and add the results to your question.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh._lastMigration/ Also, do you have any info on how random your shard key hash is?

Comment: @JohnPetrone updated, also regarding the shard key, we use openssl to generate pseudo random bytes and convert it to hex.

Comment: Can you run getShardDistribution() on your sharded collection and post the results? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getShardDistribution/ Also can you confirm that you have the default chunk size of 64 MB?

Comment: @JohnPetrone the result of getShardDistribution is in the first code block of my question, and yes the chunk size is the default one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here goes -

The behavior you are seeing appears to be normal or close to normal MongoDB sharding activity. I'll explain why in detail below.

With a default chunk size of 64MB, and 179 chunks, you have a total data size of under 11GB (that being the max of 64MB chunks time 179). It's likely well under that.

Yet you have 8 shards - which means you've distributed a (relatively) small amount of data across a large number of shards/chunks. This is resulting in some significant unevenness in data distribution that will not resolve itself until you either have many more chunks, or reduce the number of shards so that you have more chunks per shard.

First off the MongoDB balancer, contrary to common belief, does not keep everything precisely balanced. It kicks in according to certain thresholds and then turns off when other thresholds are hit. Otherwise it would thrash continuously.

The thresholds can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/

- Fewer than 20 chunks: 2 chunk difference kicks in balancer
- 20-79 chunks: 4 chunks difference kicks in balancer
- 80 and greater: 8 chunks difference kicks in balancer

In your case, with over 80 chunks, you will not migrate until the difference between the largest and the smallest shards (in numbers of chunks) is at least 8. Your max difference is 5 right now, between 25 chunks on shard0000 and 20 chunks on shard0006 and shard00007. This accounts for some significant amount of the difference.

Please note that the default balancer behavior is not to drive the difference to 0 - so when you add a new shard that new shard will start out with fewer chunks as migration stops when the difference between the largest shard and smallest shard is 2.

This difference is not that noticeable when you have a large number of chunks per shard - but you do not. So this will continue to be noticeable until you have a much higher concentration of chunks per shard.

After you add your new shards, which are smaller, the ongoing distribution of data is a function of how evenly distributed your data is across your shard key. Date based keys or other steadily increasing keys create hot spots - fully random keys come close to perfectly even distribution.

In looking at your current chunk distribution across your shards and assuming your migration balanced out to within 2 chunks per shard (note this is an assumption - it could have stopped before that with an error) it looks like you might have a not perfectly random hash key, as distribution looks to be a bit biased.

Please note that this is a "might" - might be an artifact of an incomplete balancer run that stopped due to errors.

In any event, you are unlikely to ever see "perfect" balance. You should see much closer balance after enough new data has come in such that the total number of chunks per shard is >> then threshold. Right now, with 20 - 25 chunks per shard and a start threshold of 8 difference and a stop threshold of 2 difference you will continue to see significant differences in data balance, with the older, bigger shards always staying bigger.

With the current distribution you will need a shard to hit 28 chunks while another shard sits at 20 chunks before the balancer kicks in - a difference of 40%. At that's assuming all chunks are the same size - any bias in allocation of new data to chunks will skew that number.

If you had the same number of chunks on 4 shards instead of 8, the difference at balancer kick in would only be 20%. So have a large number of shards and a small number of chunks makes this problem much worse.

One thing to further investigate is how big each chunk is - not easy to determine directly via existing MongoDB tools but there is some code out there that may help:

https://github.com/comerford/mongodb-scripts/blob/master/AllChunkInfo.js

Note that I would try it out in test first. The goal is to understand if your chunks are reasonably even in size and if not, why not.

Comment: Thanks for a really thorough and clear explanation. Last question, would manually migrating chunks to other shards (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) help?


Our shard key is using `bin2hex(openssl_pseudo_random_bytes(16))`, I was thinking of just resharding the collection and using mongo's built in hash functionality

Comment: Yes manually migrating chunks from the largest shard to the smallest would help in the overall balance.